# Loop through multidimensional JSON (Python)

Tags: python, json, list, dictionary

I have a JSON with following structure:

```
{
    'count': 93,
    'apps' : [
        {
        'last_modified_at': '2016-10-21T12:20:26Z',
        'frequency_caps': [],
        'ios': {
            'enabled': True,
            'push_enabled': False,
            'app_store_id': 'bbb',
            'connection_type': 'certificate',
            'sdk_api_secret': '--'
        },
        'organization_id': '--',
        'name': '---',
        'app_id': 27,
        'control_group_percentage': 0,
        'created_by': {
            'user_id': 'abc',
            'user_name': 'def'
        },
        'created_at': '2016-09-28T11:41:24Z',
        'web': {}
    }, {
        'last_modified_at': '2016-10-12T08:58:57Z',
        'frequency_caps': [],
        'ios': {
            'enabled': True,
            'push_enabled': True,
            'app_store_id': '386304604',
            'connection_type': 'certificate',
            'sdk_api_secret': '---',
            'push_expiry': '2018-01-14T08:24:09Z'
        },
        'organization_id': '---',
        'name': '---',
        'app_id': 87,
        'control_group_percentage': 0,
        'created_by': {
            'user_id': '----',
            'user_name': '---'
        },
        'created_at': '2016-10-12T08:58:57Z',
        'web': {}
    }
  ]
}
```

It's a JSON with two key-value-pairs. The second pair's value is a List of more JSON's.
For me it is too much information and I want to have a JSON like this:

```
{
  'apps' : [
      {
        'name': 'Appname',
        'app_id' : 1234,
        'organization_id' : 'Blablabla'
      },
      {
        'name': 'Appname2',
        'app_id' : 5678,
        'organization_id' : 'Some other Organization'
      }
   ]
}
```

I want to have a JSON that only contains one key ("apps") and its value, which would be a List of more JSONs that only have three key-value-pairs..
I am thankful for any advice.

Thank you for your help!

Comment: This should be fairly easy to achieve, did you try anything so far?

Comment: Sorry, I'm absolutely new to StackOverflow...
Yes, I've tried a for-loop which worked, but it felt wrong..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@bishakh-ghosh I don't think you need to use the input json as string. It can be used straight as a dictionary. (thus avoid `ast`)

One more concise way :

```
# your original json
input_ = { 'count': 93, ... }
```

And here are the steps :

Define what keys you want to keep

```
slice_keys = ['name', 'app_id', 'organization_id']
```

Define the new dictionary as a slice on the slice_keys

```
dict(apps=[{key:value for key,value in d.items() if key in slice_keys} for d in input_['apps']])
```

And that's it.

That should yield the JSON formatted as you want, e.g

```
{
 'apps': 
    [
     {'app_id': 27, 'name': '---', 'organization_id': '--'},
     {'app_id': 87, 'name': '---', 'organization_id': '---'}
    ]
 }
```

Comment: Thanks for the advice! Actually this was exactly what I needed! Thank you ! :-)

Answer (score 0):

This might be what you are looking for:

```
import ast
import json
json_str = """{
    'count': 93,
    'apps' : [
        {
        'last_modified_at': '2016-10-21T12:20:26Z',
        'frequency_caps': [],
        'ios': {
            'enabled': True,
            'push_enabled': False,
            'app_store_id': 'bbb',
            'connection_type': 'certificate',
            'sdk_api_secret': '--'
        },
        'organization_id': '--',
        'name': '---',
        'app_id': 27,
        'control_group_percentage': 0,
        'created_by': {
            'user_id': 'abc',
            'user_name': 'def'
        },
        'created_at': '2016-09-28T11:41:24Z',
        'web': {}
    }, {
        'last_modified_at': '2016-10-12T08:58:57Z',
        'frequency_caps': [],
        'ios': {
            'enabled': True,
            'push_enabled': True,
            'app_store_id': '386304604',
            'connection_type': 'certificate',
            'sdk_api_secret': '---',
            'push_expiry': '2018-01-14T08:24:09Z'
        },
        'organization_id': '---',
        'name': '---',
        'app_id': 87,
        'control_group_percentage': 0,
        'created_by': {
            'user_id': '----',
            'user_name': '---'
        },
        'created_at': '2016-10-12T08:58:57Z',
        'web': {}
    }
  ]
}"""

json_dict = ast.literal_eval(json_str)

new_dict = {}
app_list = []

for appdata in json_dict['apps']:
    appdata_dict = {}
    appdata_dict['name'] = appdata['name']
    appdata_dict['app_id'] = appdata['app_id']
    appdata_dict['organization_id'] = appdata['organization_id']
    app_list.append(appdata_dict)

new_dict['apps'] = app_list

new_json_str = json.dumps(new_dict)

print(new_json_str) # This is your resulting json string
```